# PowerShell console output from Tee-Object command inside function inside IF statement

Tags: powershell, console

Consider following code:

```
Function ShowSave-Log {
  Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $text)
  $PSDefaultParameterValues=@{'Out-File:Encoding' = 'utf8'}
  $date=[string](Get-Date).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
  Tee-Object -InputObject "$date $text" -FilePath $LOG_FILE -Append
  #Write-Host "$date $text"
}

Function Is-Installed {
  Param ([parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $app_name, [String] $app_version)
  $apps = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | 
  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion
  $apps += Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion
  $apps = $apps.Where{$_.DisplayName -like "$app_name"}
  if ($apps.Count -eq 0) {
    ShowSave-Log "`'$app_name`' not found in the list of installed applications."
    return $false
  } else {
    ShowSave-Log "`'$app_name`' is installed."
    return $true
  }
}

$LOG_FILE="$Env:TEMP\LOG.log"
if (Is-Installed "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)") {Write-Host "TRUE"}
```

I'd expect to see message from Tee-Object command in ShowSave-Log function, however it is never shown in terminal. I am guessing it's because it is called from 'if' statement. How can I get Tee-Object output to terminal screen ? It is saved to log file.
BTW Write-Host command correctly outputs message to terminal.
I am using PowerShell ISE, Visual Studio code and PowerShell terminal. PowerShell version 5.1

Comment: Shows just fine in my test.

Comment: what version of PowerShell did you use for testing ?

Comment: `PSVersion                      5.1.19041.610 `
`PSEdition                      Desktop`
`PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}`
`BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.610`
`CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a common misconception about how Powershell functions return data. Actually there isn't a *single* return value or object as you are used to from other programming languages. Instead, there is an *output stream* of objects.

There are several ways to add data to the output stream, e. g.:

- `Write-Output $data`
- `$data`
- `return $data`

Confusing to PS newcomers coming from other languages is the fact that `return $data` **does not define the sole "return value" of a function**. It is just a convenient way to combine `Write-Output $data` with an early exit from the function. Whatever data that was written to the output stream befor the `return` statement also contributes to the output of the function!

### Analysis of the code

> ```
> Tee-Object -InputObject "$date $text" -FilePath $LOG_FILE -Append
> ```

... appends the InputObject to the output stream of `ShowSave-Log`

> ```
> ShowSave-Log "`'$app_name`' is installed."
> ```

... appends the message to the output stream of `Is-Installed`

> ```
> return $true
> ```

... appends the value `$true` to the output stream of `Is-Installed`

Now we actually have **two** objects in the output stream of `Is-Installed`, the string message and the `$true` value!

> ```
> if (Is-Installed "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)") {Write-Host "TRUE"}
> ```

Let me split up the if-statement to explain in detail what it does:

```
$temp = Is-Installed "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)"
```

... redirects the output stream of `Is-Installed` to temporary variable. As the output stream has been stored into a variable, it won't go further up in the function call chain, so it won't show up in the console anymore! That's why you don't see the message from `Tee-Object`.

In our case there is more than one object in the output stream, so the variable will be an array like `@('... is installed', $true)`

```
if ($temp) {Write-Host "TRUE"}
```

... does an implicit boolean conversion of the array `$temp`. A non-empty array converts to `$true`. So there is a bug here, because the function `Is-Installed` always "returns" a non-empty array. When the software is not installed, `$temp` would look like `@('... not found ...', $false)`, which also converts to `$true`!

**Proof:**

```
$temp = Is-Installed "nothing"
$temp.GetType().Name    # Prints 'Object[]'
$temp[0]                # Prints '2020.12.13 12:39:37 'nothing' not found ...'
$temp[1]                # Prints 'False'
if( $temp ) {'Yes'}     # Prints 'Yes' !!!
```

### How can I get Tee-Object output to terminal screen?

Don't let it write to the output stream, which should be used only for actual data to be "returned" from a function, not for log messages.

A simple way to do that is to redirect the output of `Tee-Object` to `Write-Host`, which writes to the information stream:

```
Tee-Object -InputObject "$date $text" -FilePath $LOG_FILE -Append | Write-Host
```

A more sensible way would be to redirect to the verbose stream:

```
Tee-Object -InputObject "$date $text" -FilePath $LOG_FILE -Append | Write-Verbose
```

Now the log message doesn't clutter the terminal by default. Instead, to see detailed logging the caller has to enable verbose output, e. g. by setting `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` or calling the function with `-Verbose` parameter:

```
if( Is-Installed 'foo' -Verbose ){<# do something #>}
```

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation. I tried "sensible way" solution and it works for me. Interesting fact is, that if I replace Write-Host with Write-Output, I get no output like with Tee-Object. I suspect reason behind it is the same. I also tested your proof, and it works as you demonstrated, but only if you assign function output to variable. In my code I am not doing that and 'if' returns always correct value.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand if you think of it as

```
$result = Is-Installed "Notepad++ (64-bit x64)"
if ($result) {Write-Host "TRUE"}
```

It's pretty clear that way that the result isn't output to the console at any time.

---

You may also be misunderstanding how return works

```
    ShowSave-Log "`'$app_name`' not found in the list of installed applications."
    return $false
```

is functionally the same as

```
    ShowSave-Log "`'$app_name`' not found in the list of installed applications."
    $false
    return
```

You'd be better of having your functions return simple PowerShell objects rather than human readable text and truth values.

```
function Get-InstalledApps {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $app_name,
        [string] $app_version
    )
    $installPaths = @(
        'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
        'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    )
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $installPaths | Where-Object DisplayName -like $app_name
}
```

And leave the formatting for the user to the top level of your script.

---

It could be worth looking at custom types with the `DefaultDisplayPropertySet` property. For example:

```
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'InstalledApp' -DefaultDisplayPropertySet 'DisplayName', 'DisplayVersion'

function Get-InstalledApps {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $app_name,
        [string] $app_version
    )
    $installPaths = @(
        'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
        'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    )
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $installPaths | Where-Object DisplayName -like $app_name | Add-Member -TypeName 'InstalledApp' -PassThru
}
```

Or without a custom type, this abomination of a one liner:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $installPaths | Where-Object DisplayName -like $app_name | Add-Member -MemberType MemberSet -Name PSStandardMembers -Value ([System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]](New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet DefaultDisplayPropertySet, ([string[]]('DisplayName', 'DisplayVersion')))) -PassThru
```

---

Also worth taking a look at is the [Approved Verbs for PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) page.